# SQL sum up multiple measured data over an hour by hour in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a load of data measured over a year, multiple times an hour and i want to sum those data up by an hour and then sum all columns. i'm doing it in ACCESSS and i just don't know how to make the script work in this idiotic software. I'm working on this already over few hours, and without proper debug it is like finding needle in haystack, and if some script works normally in sql it just won't in the Access, and every tutorial or document i found would every time lead me on how to calculate the time difference. So if anyone knows how to do this i would be very grateful.

The table looks like this

```
Time                 Column1       Column2
12.12.2014 5:20      0             0
12.12.2014 5:30      15            5
12.12.2014 5:45      50            12
12.12.2014 5:55      120           8
12.12.2014 6:25      300           25
12.12.2014 6:40      240           50
```

and i want it to look like this

```
Date         Hour          SUM(Column1)       SUM(Column2)       Summary
12.12.2014   6             185                25                 210
12.12.2014   7             540                75                 615
```

Tried doing it through DatePart, but it always fail.

Comment: Please edit the question with what you tried and the results. [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why hours 6 and 7 instead of 5 and 6? This appears to be a fairly simple aggregate query.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need a script but a query (air code) like this:

```sql
Select
    DateValue([Time]) As [Date],
    Hour(-Int(-TimeValue([Time]) * 24) / 24) As [Hour],
    Sum([Column1]) As Total1,
    Sum([Column2]) As Total2,
    Sum([Column1]) + Sum([Column2]) As Summary
From
    YourTable
Group By
    DateValue([Time]),
    Hour(-Int(-TimeValue([Time]) * 24) / 24)
```

Comment: Nice looking solution, but my question is the Time in your solution in Date/Time DataType ? and if it is what is the format you are using for it as im using the dd\.mm\.yyyy\ h:nn and its just sayin invalid Data Type

Comment: Data type _Date_ carries no format. What you see is only your default date/time format applied to the values. _Invalid data type_ means, that either your field is not of data type _Date_, or some records have _Null_ values which must be filtered out or replaced with a default value. If the data type of the field is _Text_, it must be converted. Check that.